# Xamarin.Forms DependencyService cannot share interface cross-platform in file handling

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, uwp, xamarin.android, .net-standard-2.0

I am following the [official Xamarin guide](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/application-fundamentals/files/#Loading_and_Saving_Files) for cross-platform file handling using `.net-standard-2.0` PCL project. The App is intended to build for Android and Windows.

It raises me a question here. The interface code is as below.

```
public interface ISaveAndLoad {
    void SaveText (string filename, string text);
    string LoadText (string filename);
}
```

However, the code given for UWP is written as

```
[assembly: Dependency(typeof(SaveAndLoad_WinApp))]
namespace WindowsApp
{
    // https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/hh758325.aspx
    public class SaveAndLoad_WinApp : ISaveAndLoad
    {
        public async Task SaveTextAsync(string filename, string text)
        {
            StorageFolder localFolder = ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder;
            StorageFile sampleFile = await localFolder.CreateFileAsync(filename, CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting);
            await FileIO.WriteTextAsync(sampleFile, text);
        }
        public async Task<string> LoadTextAsync(string filename)
        {
            StorageFolder storageFolder = ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder;
            StorageFile sampleFile = await storageFolder.GetFileAsync(filename);
            string text = await Windows.Storage.FileIO.ReadTextAsync(sampleFile);
            return text;
        }
    }
}
```

The code will not compile as `SaveAndLoad_WinApp` does not implement the interface `ISaveAndLoad`.

I know that I can change the interface to `Task` and `Task<string>`, so it will compile.

However the problems goes back to Android.
UWP is using this `Windows.Storage.FileIO` thing which does not exists on Android. While Android is using `System.IO`, it does not have a Async method that can be awaited. That means I cannot share the interface as UWP require `async Task<string>` but Android only returns a `string` instead of a `Task`.

If I am not using `async` in the UWP method, `FileIO` won't work vice versa. `async void` for `SaveText` works fine as the Interface states `void`. However, it won't allow me to make `async string` for `LoadText` as async method must return a `Task<T>`, `Task` or `void`.

It seems that the way to go will be implement async on Android too while letting the code run synchronous. However, I feel like I have done something wrong as the Xamarin sample is showing that it should work.

Am I misunderstanding anything here or missing an implementation? Or it is actually wrong in the Xamarin documentation?

---

**UPDATE #1**
I have put an `async void` for `SaveText` and realize that there's a problem that the thread is not awaited. That it fast forwarded to the next function. So I actually have to await the function in the PCL for UWP. However the implementation on Android is a `void` that cannot be awaited. So it is actually causing an Error...
Is there any suggestion on how to implement this scenario?

Here is the code I put in my PCL

```
public static void Save(){
    DependencyService.Get<ISaveAndLoad>().SaveText("temp.txt", input.Text);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The code will not compile as SaveAndLoad_WinApp does not implement the interface ISaveAndLoad.

You could download the document sample [WorkingWithFiles](https://developer.xamarin.com/samples/xamarin-forms/WorkingWithFiles/), you could find it [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mpm8g.png). In this sample the [ISaveAndLoad](https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-forms-samples/blob/master/WorkingWithFiles/PCL/WorkingWithFiles/ISaveAndLoad.cs) interface has a little difference :

```
public interface ISaveAndLoad
{
    Task SaveTextAsync (string filename, string text);
    Task<string> LoadTextAsync (string filename);
    bool FileExists (string filename);
}
```

> UWP is using this Windows.Storage.FileIO thing which does not exists on Android. While Android is using System.IO, it does not have a Async method that can be awaited.

You could refer to [SaveAndLoad_Android.cs](https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-forms-samples/blob/master/WorkingWithFiles/PCL/Android/SaveAndLoad_Android.cs) class in the sample project,  use [StreamWriter.WriteAsync()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.streamwriter.writeasync(v=vs.110).aspx) method :

```
public class SaveAndLoad_Android : ISaveAndLoad
{
    #region ISaveAndLoad implementation

    public async Task SaveTextAsync (string filename, string text)
    {
        var path = CreatePathToFile (filename);
        using (StreamWriter sw = File.CreateText (path))
            await sw.WriteAsync(text);
    }

    public async Task<string> LoadTextAsync (string filename)
    {
        var path = CreatePathToFile (filename);
        using (StreamReader sr = File.OpenText(path))
            return await sr.ReadToEndAsync();
    }

    public bool FileExists(string filename)
    {
        return File.Exists(CreatePathToFile(filename));
    }

    #endregion

    string CreatePathToFile(string filename)
    {
        var docsPath = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal);
        return Path.Combine(docsPath, filename);
    }
}
```

Then in your `PCL`, use [SaveTextAsync](https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-forms-samples/blob/master/WorkingWithFiles/PCL/WorkingWithFiles/SaveAndLoadText.cs) method like this :

```
var fileService = DependencyService.Get<ISaveAndLoad> ();
...
saveButton.Clicked += async (sender, e) => 
{
    loadButton.IsEnabled = saveButton.IsEnabled = false;
    // uses the Interface defined in this project, and the implementations that must
    // be written in the iOS, Android and WinPhone app projects to do the actual file manipulation

    await fileService.SaveTextAsync (fileName, input.Text);
    loadButton.IsEnabled = saveButton.IsEnabled = true;
};
```